# JQuery Bootstrap Modal not closing after get call

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a JQuery which gets a list of data from a java backend. This works perfectly. What I am trying to do is show a loading modal while the backend bean is running and hide the loading modal when it's complete and returned the data.

I have tried ('toggle'), ('hide') the .close click() .done() .fail() .always() as below but nothing seems to work.

It shows the modal when I click the button and I can see the data is loaded into the select list on the html page, but the loading modal does not close after the get is complete.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loadingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"><h4>Loading....</h4></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="spinner-grow text-primary" role="status">
                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="getContent()">Get Content</button>

<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="primaryList"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getContent() {
        $('#loadingModal').modal('show');

        $.get("/admin/getPrimaryList/", function(data) {
            if(data.length == 0)
            {
                $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
                return false;
            }
            data.forEach(function(item, i) {
                var option = "<option value='" + item + "'>" + item + "</option>";
                $("#primaryList").append(option);
            });
        }).done(function() {
            $("#loadingModal").modal('hide');
        }).fail(function() {
            $("#loadingModal").modal('hide');
        }).always(function() {
            $("#loadingModal").modal('hide');
        });

        $("#loadingModal").modal('hide');
    };
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can't find any element with the ID `loadingModal` or any element with the class `close` within it.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question now to show how I tried it. Previous code was a different attempt which also did not work.

Comment: try add a `console.log("test")` in your `done, fail,always ` calls, and see if you can see the message in the console

Comment: I have placed console.log("test 1") in done, console.log("test 2") in fail, console.log("test 3") in always. test 1 and test 3 gets printed, but the modal stays open. I almost get this feeling that the code is running to fast and while the modal is 'showing', the 'hide' already ran, thus keeping it open. Not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine for me. Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/v7kwo8x1/23/

The only difference here between my fiddle and your sample is that I used `jQuery` to hook up the click event. Please check if your code throws any `javascript` errors when it runs.

Placing the hide modal call either at the end of the successful callback

```
$.get('URL', function(data) {
    ...
    $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
});
```

or inside the `done` callback worked.

```
$.get('URL', function(data) {
    ...

}).done(function() {
    $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am not having any fun. I think the call to the backing data .get is taking to long and then JQuery is not catching up, or being executed to quick. Not sure what it is, but I have no errors and the modal is not closing.

Comment: Thanks, I used the SBAdmin2 layout for my site and the css or js files which comes with it must have caused the issue. I tried your solution outside the template and it worked 100%.